# How to check object is null or empty in C#.NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

If objects contains null or empty then how to validate or check the condition for the same?

How to bool check whether object **obj** is `null` or `Empty`

I've code as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object obj = null;

        double d = Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()) ? 0.0 : obj);
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
    }
}
```

With this code i'm getting `NullReference Exception` as  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Pls help.

Here I'm not getting....

**How to validate whether that object is `null` or `Empty` without converting into .ToString() ??**

Is there an approach to check the same??

Comment: You cannot convert a null object to string, thus the error. What's wrong with just checking if(obj != null) ?

Comment: Why would you call `ToString()` on an object you know is `null`, and therefore generates `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty object (though there is such a thing as the empty string).

Comment: I think this might just be example code to show the problem...

Comment: Regarding your edit, what do you think an empty object represents?

Comment: @phoog The empty in IsNullOrEmpty, refers to a string that has no characters in it.  It has a length of 0.

Comment: (sorry, I can't edit comments on my phone for some reason) or, perhaps a better question: *why* do you want to check if the object is null or empty?

Comment: @StefanH I know that, but he's talking about an object, not a string.

Comment: @phoog That would be becasue a null or empty string cannot be handled by Convert.ToDouble.

Comment: How to check if the `object` is empty??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem that you are running into is that your object is of type, well, object.  In order to evaluate it with string.IsNullOrEmpty, you should pass your object in with the cast to (string)

like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object obj = null;

    double d = Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)obj) ? 0.0 : obj);
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
}
```

This will work fine since you are not explicitly calling .ToString on your (nonexistent) object.

Comment: Assuming that `obj` is generated by a more complex process than simply setting it to `null`, the cast would fail in the case where that process produces a real object that isn't a string.

Comment: Correct, this is assuming that the object in this case would either be null or something that can be converted to a string.

Comment: Technically, this is assuming that the object can be cast to string, not just converted. This failed for me when obj was actually an int, with int.ToString() working, but (string)int failing. It's too bad; I was trying to avoid the extra ToString().

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the null reference because you are executing `obj.ToString()` which will return obj's ToString() method return value. Problem is that in the previous line you set obj to null so you will get an object reference not... error

To make your code work you need to do:

```
//This will check if it's a null and then it will return 0.0 otherwise it will return your obj.
double d = Convert.ToDouble(obj ?? 0.0);
```

Your code as it is now however will always be 0.0

Without null coalescing: (??)

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(obj ? 0.0 : obj);
```

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly from the comments you want to know if the object is null or an empty string. You can do this by casting it to string first instead of calling the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method which does something entirely different:

```
string objString = (obj as string);
double d = Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty(objString) ? "0.0" : objString);
```

Comment: ok....How to validate whether that  object is `null` or `empty` without convert to `.ToString()` ??

Comment: Like you did except that you don't call the ToString method

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr there is no cast to string; calling ToString is not a cast.

Comment: Yeah, it's awesome, just like c# :-)

Comment: but this approach doesn't handle empty strings

Comment: Very first time i'm hearing about `null-coalescing` operator and makes exciting to know more about the new thing about this operator.  Can you give some detail about the importance and benefits of this operator in the situations where i can be used the same with simple and good examples.

Comment: If the object `obj` is `empty` then how to validate?

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr: Still i didn't find your edit or updated comment and still i'm not getting to handle if the object is `Empty`?

Comment: After the bold EDIT in my answer? Do you want to check for an empty String?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object obj = DBNull.Value;
        if(obj != DBNull.Value) {
            double d = Convert.ToDouble(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `??` operator.  It is known as the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator.

Comment: Very first time i'm hearing about `null-coalescing` operator and makes exciting to know more about the new thing about this operator.  Can you give some detail about the importance and benefits of this operator in the situations where i can be used the same with simple and good examples.

Comment: If the object is `empty` then how to validate?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is this:

```
object obj = null;
double d;

if (!double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(obj), out d))
{
   d = 0.0;
}
```

But the question does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be a bit surprised that you get a `NullReferenceException` with this code.  The offending part is

```
obj.ToString()
```

If you wrote

```
object obj = null;
string s = obj.ToString();
```

you would expect a `NullReferenceException`.  Since the call to `ToString` occurs before the call to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, the exception is thrown before there is a check for a null or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Following code could be a safer way of achieving it.

```
if(obj != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
{

}
```

This code saves us from object being a non-string type.

Comment: Where does the `.Value` property come from?

Comment: My bad..Updated it..Cheers mate!

Comment: BTW, the OP did ask `without converting into .ToString()`.